# Invalid column name 'CreatedOn' using EntityFramework on Windows Azure

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

Using ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework 6 Code First on SQL Express everything runs fine on my local machine. When I publish to Windows Azure things start to fall apart. The default MVC page displays just fine. And I think the data is correct because I can compare the Azure database with my local SQL Express and everything is identical except for a couple records in __MigrationHistory. This is a new app, so I don't think the other SO issues about converting from previous versions of EF apply.

When I try to access a page that queries the database I get the following exception when I attach the Visual Studio debugger to the Azure web site. It fails on the first call to dbContext.SingleOrDefault. Note that I can see the full data of the dbContext in the debugger when it pauses.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred
  _HResult=-2146232060
  _message=Invalid column name 'CreatedOn'.
  HResult=-2146232060
  IsTransient=false
  Message=Invalid column name 'CreatedOn'.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  _doNotReconnect=false
  Class=16
  LineNumber=2
  Number=207
  Procedure=""
  Server=tcp:*.database.windows.net,1433
  State=1
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
  InnerException:
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code that throws this exception, along with your model.

Comment: Yes, paste code snippet, model and check the Azure SQL DB schema. I believe that you have first published your solution, which created the D, then you added this column, but didn'T execute migrations on the Azure SQL DB! And something more - you can run and debug locally with the Azure Connection string. No need to publish to the web site to see the result from SQL Azure...

Comment: I guess there was something wrong with my migrations, but I never had column called CreatedOn. Using the Azure Connection string was  a great help to getting this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is something to do with Migrations and the removal of the CreatedOn column.

I get this exception using the MiniProfiler. I deleted the pdb files from the bin folder (as suggested in a post in the MiniProfiler github site) and it no longer happens.

You might want to check references to EF as it could be a reference in a [nuget] package built against an earlier version of EF.